# migrate over odoo v10 to odoo v13 getting error in Onchange func

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

Fields definition:

```
    time_task_ids = fields.One2many('timesheet.timesheet','timesheet_id','Timesheet')
    timesheet_id = fields.Many2one('timesheet.timesheet', 'Timesheet', compute='_compute_timesheet_id')
    Transient_model_name = 'timesheet.data'
```

Method that could cause this problem:

```
        @api.onchange('created_by','created_date')
        def on_change_created_by(self):

            # list the task in timesheet based on user
            task_ids = self.env['prj.task'].search([('task_assigned_to','=',self.created_by.id),
                                                    ('state','=','ongoing'),('child_ids','=',False)])
            task_list = []
            for task in task_ids:
                timesheet = self.env['timesheet.timesheet'].search([('task_ids', '=', task.id)])
                tot_time = 0
                for i in timesheet:
                    tot_time += i.duration
                tot_duration = task.task_planned_hours - tot_time
                vals = {
                    'task_ids': task.id,
                    'created_date': self.created_date,
                    'created_by': self.created_by.id,
                    'prj_project_id':task.prj_project_id.id,
                    'planned_hour': task.task_planned_hours,
                    'task_deadline_date': task.task_deadline_date,
                    'balance_hour': tot_duration,
                    'ref_parent_id':  task.task_assigned_to.parent_id.id,
                }
                task_list.append((0, 0, vals))
            self.time_task_ids = task_list
```

Error Traceback :

```
    2020-02-24 09:29:28,448 10954 ERROR new_db3 odoo.http: Exception during JSON request handling. 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 619, in _handle_exception
        return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 309, in _handle_exception
        raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 664, in dispatch
        result = self._call_function(**self.params)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 345, in _call_function
        return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/service/model.py", line 93, in wrapper
        return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 338, in checked_call
        result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 910, in __call__
        return self.method(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/http.py", line 510, in response_wrap
        response = f(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1320, in call_kw
        return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1312, in _call_kw
        return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/api.py", line 395, in call_kw
        result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/api.py", line 382, in _call_kw_multi
        result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/models.py", line 6056, in onchange
        record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/models.py", line 5857, in _onchange_eval
        method_res = method(self)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/addons/ajax_timesheet/wizard/wizard_timesheet.py", line 98, in on_change_created_by
        self.time_task_ids = task_list
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 1068, in __set__
        self.write(new_records, value)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 2758, in write
        return self.write_batch([(records, value)])
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 2782, in write_batch
        return self.write_new(records_commands_list)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 3002, in write_new
        line[inverse] = record
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/models.py", line 5598, in __setitem__
        return self._fields[key].__set__(self, value)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 1068, in __set__
        self.write(new_records, value)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 2467, in write
        cache_value = self.convert_to_cache(value, records)
      File "/home/guru/Documents/odoo-13/odoo/fields.py", line 2400, in convert_to_cache
        raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %r" % (self, value))
    ValueError: Wrong value for timesheet.timesheet.timesheet_id: timesheet.data(<NewId 0x7fba579107b8>,)
```

give me a solution to solve this error. 
error occurs in one2many to list assignment

Comment: can you show the code of `_compute_timesheet_id`

Comment: @api.depends('created_by') def _compute_timesheet_id(self): for rec in self: rec.timesheet_id = rec. _origin.id

Comment: This is wrong and make no sense at all, and this is your problem, when you create a record this will cause a problem? What are you doing exactly with this field that points to the record itself?!!!

Comment: Compute field is in different model which i am passing values to.. problem only occurs while equate one2many field with list of values. ( These codes works fine in v10)